# how to get a single item returned when a div is clicked in aurelia

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, aurelia, model-binding

i have a div that when you click it,it opens a modal. as follows

```
<div if.bind="Members.length" click.delegate="GetProfiles($event.target)">
                <div repeat.for="category of Types(Members)">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col s3">
                            <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
                                <div class="rotate-text-90-negative truncate">
                                    ${category.name}
                                </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

so when the page loads and i have 3 category names displayed for example

***Stationary***

***Office Equipment***

***Cleaning supplies***

now when i click on ***Stationary*** i want it to open the "GetProfiles($event.target)" modal i have which it does as follows

```
<div md-modal="
         in-duration: 1000;
         out-duration: 1000;
         dismissible:false;
         "
         md-modal.ref="GetProfile">
        <div class="modal-content">
            
            <div>
                <div >
                    <md-input label="First Name" readonly.bind="false"></md-input>
                
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

i have the following on my type script page

```
async GetCrewProfiles(Members) {
        this.GetProfile.open();
        console.log(Members);
}
```

but now when i log the members out it comes back with all the members array as follows:

```
0:{Name:"Stationary" Id:"12365" active:true stock:"50"}
1:{Name:"Office Equipment" Id:"1278365" active:true stock:"0"}
2:{Name:"Cleaning supplies" Id:"12395" active:true stock:"5"}
```

how do i create an event that only returns the Member that i clicked on, so if i clicked on Stationary i only want to get the information for that and not return everything

i tried this

```
GetProfiles($event.target) and GetProfiles(Members)
```

but i cant figure out how to add a click event for a selected item

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried moving your click.delegate function inside the repeat.for div?

I suggest you to move your **click.delegate** inside the **repeat.for** div. Something like this:

```
<div if.bind="Members.length">
                <div repeat.for="category of Types(Members)">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col s3">
                            <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
                                <div click.delegate="GetProfiles($event.target)" 
                                class="rotate-text-90-negative truncate"> ${category.name}
                                </div>
                             </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
               </div>
</div>
```